# How would i pull zend mail addresses from a table

Tags: zend-framework

I have a .php file that has a list of email addresses in zend_mail. When a user sends out an alert message, say a bus broke down, the alert goes to my database and everyone on the email list. I would like the email addresses to come from table rather than be hard coded into the php file

We are only hard coding right now, sometimes twenty addresses, for each php file

```
try {
            $mail = new Zend_Mail();

            $mail->addTo('johnnywalker@comcast.net');
            $mail->addTo('mjimeez@thistransportation.com');
            $mail->addTo('aburrow@thistransportation.com');
```

If the code were to say try{ from mytable which contains a list of addresses in column a,where column b = 1,representing which php files go to which employees

Comment: Learning ZF3 (I know you tagged ZF1 and are using `Zend_Mail`, but seeing as you have problems with the basics, a simultaneous upgrade cannot hurt, only enhance) tutorials [here](https://docs.zendframework.com/tutorials/). Vanilla PHP (no framework/cms) could also be an idea to learn the basics, try [here](https://www.udemy.com/php-mysql-tutorial/) (costs money I think) (and possible [free here](https://www.siteground.com/tutorials/php-mysql/)). Give that a shot, then update your question with what you tried, any problems, errors, etc.

Answer (score 0):

```
 $sql = $dbRead->quoteInto("SELECT alertID,[alertDescription],count(*) as [Count] FROM         dbo.ActiveAlerts WHERE subdomain = ? GROUP by alertID, [alertDescription]",$subdomain);
    $resultAlerts = $dbRead->fetchAll($sql);
    foreach($resultAlerts as $x){$alertIDs .= $x['alertID']."|";}; //load for controller 

    Then this adds it to the table
$alertID = "1001"; //incident updates
    if(strstr($alertIDsOK,$alertID)) {  
            try {
                $sql = $dbRead->quoteInto("SELECT email FROM dbo.ActiveAlerts WHERE alertID = ?",$alertID);
                $resultEmail = $dbRead->fetchAll($sql);

                $mail = new Zend_Mail();
                foreach($resultEmail as $m){
                $mail->addTo($m['email']);}
```